# What is the closest point to a plane?

Tags: 3d

I can't solve this question: Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the plane containing the points $(-3,4,-2)$, $(1,4,0)$, and $(3,2,-1)$.
Find the point in this plane that is closest to $(0,3,-1)$.

I don't know how to do this question. Any hints/solutions? If it is vectors, then I am pretty sure I don't know how to do it. :(

Comment: Do you know how to find the normal to the plane?

Comment: Never heard of it :( I just searched it up and its calc... Is there a way to do it with algebra, geo, or vectors?

Comment: Use cross product

Comment: ... what is that... Can you explain it???

Comment: What course is this for? It seems like if you are discussing planes, you would also presumably be discussing vectors.

Comment: It is from a Precalculus course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the orthogonal projection $H$  of the $M(0,3,-1)$ onto the plane defined by the points $A(-3,4,-2)$, $B(1,4,0)$ and $C(3,2,-1)$.

- If the vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$ are orthogonal, it is given by the formula
  $$\overrightarrow{AH}=\frac{\overrightarrow{AM}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}}{\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}}\,\overrightarrow{AB}+\frac{\overrightarrow{AM}\cdot\overrightarrow{AC}}{\overrightarrow{AC}\cdot\overrightarrow{AC}}\,\overrightarrow{AC}.\tag{1}$$
  To end determining the point $H$, just calculate 
  $$\overrightarrow{OH}=\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{AH}.$$
- If the vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC}$ are not orthogonal, you first have to deduce an orthogonal basis of the plane $\bigl\langle\overrightarrow{AB}, \overrightarrow{AC}\bigr\rangle$ by *Gram-Schmidt process*: if $$\overrightarrow{AC'}=\overrightarrow{AC}-\frac{\overrightarrow{AM}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}}{\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}}\,\overrightarrow{AB},$$
  the vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$ and $\overrightarrow{AC'}$ are orthogonal, and you can apply  formula  $(1)$.

Comment: In the formula for $\overrightarrow{AH}$, there's a missing $\overrightarrow{AC}$ in the denominator of the second term.

Comment: Why is this formula for $\overrightarrow{AH}$ is *correct*?  If I put $A=(0,0,0),B=(1,2,0),C=(-1,2,0),M=(0,1,1)$, then points $A,B,C$ should be *symmetric* about the $y$-axis, and plane $\cal P$ should be the $xy$-plane, while the orthogonal projection $H$ is *expected* to be $(0,1,0)$ *by symmetry and observation*.  However, in your formula, the 1st term is $$\frac{\overrightarrow{AM}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}}{\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{AB}}\,\overrightarrow{AB}=\frac25(1,2,0),$$ while the 2nd term is $\frac25(-1,2,0)$ by symmetry.  They *don't* add up to $(0,1,0)$ as expected.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: Sorry. I forgot to say the formula is valid for an orthogonal family of vectors. I've updated my answer. Thank you for pointing the problem!

Comment: It's very kind of you to respond to my question. +1

Answer (score 2):

1. Find two vectors lying on the plane: $v_1=(-3,4,-2)-(1,4,0)=(-4,0,-2)$ and $v_2=(1,4,0)-(3,2,-1)=(-2,2,1)$.  Rescale $v_1$ to $(2,0,1)$ for simplicity.
2. Compute their cross product to obtain a normal vector $v_3$ for the plane.
   $$v_3 = v_1\times v_2=\left|
   \begin{matrix}
   {\bf i} & {\bf j} & {\bf k} \\
   2&0&1\\-2&2&1
   \end{matrix}
   \right|
   =-2{\bf i}-4{\bf j}+4{\bf k}
   $$
3. Parametrize the straight line $L$ passing through $(0,3,-1)$ with the direction $v_3$ (i.e. normal to the plane) with $(0,3,-1)+tv_3 \,\forall t\in\Bbb R$.
   $$(0,3,-1)+tv_3=(-2t,3-4t,-1+4t) \tag{$L$}\label{L}$$
   Each point on $L$ corresponds to a value of $t$.
4. Find the intersection of $L$ with the plane.  Let $x\in L \cap{\cal P}$.  Since $x \in L$, express $x$ in terms of $t$: $x=(-2t,3-4t,-1+4t)$.  It's given that $(-3,4,-2)$ lies on the plane, so
   \begin{align}
   v=x-(-3,4,-2)&=(-2t,3-4t,-1+4t)-(-3,4,-2)\\
   &=(3-2t,-1-4t,1+4t)
   \end{align}
   is parallel to the plane.
5. Compute the dot product $v\cdot v_3 = 0$ in terms of $t$.  ($v$ is parallel to the plane, while $v_3$ is normal to the plane.)
   \begin{align}
   v\cdot v_3&=(3-2t,-1-4t,1+4t)\cdot(-2,-4,4)\\
   &=-6+4t+4+16t+4+16t\\
   &=36t+2 = 0 \\
   \therefore t &=-\frac{1}{18} \\
   x&=\left(-2\left(-\frac{1}{18}\right),3-4\left(-\frac{1}{18}\right),-1+4\left(-\frac{1}{18}\right)\right) \\
   &= \left(\frac{1}{9},\frac{29}{9},-\frac{11}{9}\right)
   \end{align}
   So the required distance is
   \begin{align}
   {\rm dist}((0,3,-1),x) &= \sqrt{\left(\frac19\right)^2+\left(\frac{29}{9}-3\right)^2+\left(-\frac{11}{9}+1\right)^2} \\
   &= \frac{\sqrt{1^2+2^2+(-2)^2}}{9} = \frac13
   \end{align}